# how to chain jQuery onchange event like?

Tags: jquery

```
input#one
input#two
input#three

$('#one').change(function() {
  $('#two').val('change_by_one');
});

$('#two').change(function() {
  $('#three').val('changed');
});
```

I want to chain the change event, so when I change `#one`, it will change `#two` then `#three ...`
I tried

```
$('#one').change(function() {
  $('#two').val('change_by_one');
  // at this point, the changed value of `#two` is not rendered yet, resulting some invalid state.
  $('#two').trigger('change'); 
});
```

Any idea how to achieve that? Chain events

==============update===============
a better example to my issue is:

```
<select id="organisation">
    <option value="org1">org1</option>
    <option value="org2">org2</option>
</select>

<select id='media'>
</select>

<input placeholder="get the selected media"/>

var $media = $('#media');
$('#organisation').change(function() {
  var options = [];
  setTimeout(function() {
    $media.append('<option value="image" data-type="image">image</option>');
    $media.append('<option value="first" data-type="video">video</option>');
  }, 1000);
    $media.change();
});

$('#media').change(function() {
  $('input').val($('#media').val());
});
```

Select organisation do ajax call to get it's media files, and render the options in the media select, I just want some onchange event for media field triggered when organisation is changed.

I have make an example.
https://jsfiddle.net/rht3Lxav/

============= solution ==========

```
var $media = $('#media');

$('#organisation').change(function() {
  var options = [];
    AddOptions().then(function() {
        $media.change();
    });
});

$('#media').change(function() {
  $('input').val($('#media').val());
});

function AddOptions() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $media.find('option').remove().end();
        $media.append('<option value="image" data-type="image">image</option>');
        $media.append('<option value="first" data-type="video">video</option>');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would like something like Promise, one event finished, then automatically fire another event based on the last changed field.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve/why. When you do this: `$('#two').val('change_by_one');`, that is creating a 'change' event (because you changed its value), and then you straight away call `$('#two').trigger('change');` which triggers a 2nd change. Just remove `$('#two').trigger('change');` ?

Comment: @ash Sorry for the unclear description, I have just updated the question to make it more understandable, really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like that :

```
$('#one').change(function() {
  $('#two').val('change_by_one').change();
});

$('#two').change(function() {
  $('#three').val('change_by_two').change();
});

$('#three').change(function() {
  $('#four').val('change_by_three');
});
```

You can test it here : https://jsfiddle.net/m2gb3yj1/9/

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle too, and update my question, I think my issue is asnyc call in onchange event.

Sorry about vague description, my code is too complex to copy here.
this is the simplified version.

Comment: I updated your fiddle to work asynchronously even though I don't understand well why you need something like that. https://jsfiddle.net/rht3Lxav/9/