# is it possible? onChange from one spreadsheet triggers onChange from another spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that when the onchange triggers it makes a mirror of the information to use as a reference later when it determine which rows changed.  I had this connected to a Query function.  Whenever the query got updated, the onChange function would run.  But sometimes the query would act weird and information would appear blank on the sheet it copies to even though i can see it on the query. And if two computers were looking at the query at the same time, it was evident that it didn't update on all screens.  So i decided, why not, instead of a query, we have the information get updated the same way the mirror is updated. So it copies all the information down and puts it onto the sheet, no query needed.  I figured this would at least make sure everyone is seeing the same information.  So i made a query sheet, and added an onChange() trigger to it that grabbed all the info and pasted it onto the main sheet, whenever the query updated.  (even if it messes up, at least it's much more obvious and no one is seeing anything different).  But when the information was posted onto the main spreadsheet.  THAT spreadsheet's onChange function didn't trigger.  I thought it would trigger whenever there was a change.  No matter what.  So I then decided to create a new function in the Query Sheet where it inserts and deletes the last row, even say hi, thinking if I make the sheet change more prominently, the onChange() function would trigger.  Still didn't.  I'm at a loss.

```
function onChangeMirror() {
  var sos = SpreadsheetApp.openById("the sheet with the query");
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = s1.getLastRow();
  var lastRow1 = s1.getLastRow()+1;
  var lastRow10 = s1.getLastRow() +10;
  var SRange = s1.getRange(2,1,lastRow,2);
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  var sos2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("the sheet it's updating");
  var sas2 = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos2);
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s2 = ss2.getActiveSheet();
  var MaxRow = s2.getMaxRows();
  s2.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
  Logger.log(lastRow1)
  Logger.log(lastRow10)
  s2.getRange('A'+ lastRow1+':'+'B'+lastRow10).setValue(null);
  Logger.log(A1Range)
  if(MaxRow > '300') {
    s2.deleteRow(MaxRow)
  }
  else if(MaxRow < '301'){
    s2.insertRowAfter(MaxRow)
    s2.getRange('A'+(MaxRow+1)).setValue('HI')
  }
}
```

here is the script i was using

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312135/how-to-chain-jquery-onchange-event-like

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of the question at the link provided in the previous comment.  It is possible to delete your own comment.